# c++ has no member named xy error i get when using an enum

Tags: c++

i have an enum type called TokenType that looks like this:

```
#ifndef TOKENTYPE_H_
#define TOKENTYPE_H_

    class TokenType{
    public:
        enum TType{
            INTEGER,
            IDENTIFIER,
            PRINT,
            READ,
            SIGN_PLUS           ='+',
            SIGN_MINUS          ='-',
            SIGN_DIV            ='/',
            SIGN_MUL            ='*',
            SIGN_LESSTHAN       ='<',
            SIGN_GREATERTHAN    ='>',
            SIGN_EQUALS         ='=',
            SIGN_DOUBLEEQUALS   ='==',
            SIGN_NOTEQUALS      ='=!=',
            SIGN_NOT            ='!',
        };
    };



#endif /* TOKENTYPE_H_ */
```

When i try to compile my class token i get an error that says

```
In file included from Token.h:10:0,
                 from Token.cpp:10:
TokenType.h:25:23: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
TokenType.h:26:21: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
Token.cpp: In constructor ‘Token::Token(int, int, TokenType, int)’:
Token.cpp:15:8: error: ‘class Token’ has no member named ‘TokenType’
Token.cpp: In member function ‘void Token::setValue(int*)’:
Token.cpp:20:19: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
Token.cpp: In member function ‘void Token::testPrint()’:

Token.cpp:24:89: error: expected primary-expression before ‘<<’ token
```

class Token has no member named TokenType is probably the culprit here.

Token.h looks like this:

```
#ifndef TOKEN_H_
#define TOKEN_H_
#include "TokenType.h"


class Token {

    int line;
    int column;
    TokenType tokenType;
    int valueInt; //bei Integern muss Value gespeichert werden
    int infoKey; //der Key aus der Symtableh

public:
    Token(int line, int column, TokenType tokenType, int infoKey);
    void setValue(int* value);
    void testPrint();
    virtual ~Token();
};

#endif /* TOKEN_H_ */
```

And finally token.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Token.h"

Token:: Token(int line, int column, TokenType TType, int infoKey) {
    this->line = line;
    this->column = column;
    this->TokenType = TType;
    this->infoKey = infoKey;
}

void Token::setValue(int* value){
    this->valueInt = value;
}

void Token::testPrint(){
    cout << "Token: Line: " << line << " Column: " << column << " TokenType: " <<TokenType << " Infokey: " <<infoKey;
}

Token::~Token() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
```

Why doesn't token find tokentype? i'm just a beginner in c++. 
Please help me.

Thanks in advance,

kind regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler tells you what is wrong.

`Token.cpp:15:8: error: ‘class Token’ has no member named ‘TokenType’`

You have member `tokenType` of type `TokenType`.

Next:

```
Token.cpp: In member function ‘void Token::setValue(int*)’:
Token.cpp:20:19: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
```

You defined  `valueInt` as `int` but your function defines `value` as `int*`. It is a type miss-match. There is no point in passing arguments to setters by refererence for primitive types. So I would suggest changing it to `void Token::setValue(int value)`. You could also write `void Token::setValue(const int& value)`.

Last, but not least, compiler tells you: `TokenType.h:25:23: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]`
You get a warning because in `c/c++` this notation `'c'` used for **single charcaters only**. This:

```
 SIGN_DOUBLEEQUALS   ='==',
 SIGN_NOTEQUALS      ='=!=',
```

This is not and error but will most probably not work as you expect it to. There is no way to get this properly done with `enum` for single characters, as only the single characters can be represented as numbers which are suitable to use with enumerator.

Comment: It's not error, it's warning. It can work, but can not. `enum` in C++98 has implementation-defined underlying type.

Comment: @ForEveR Oh I didn't change it. My bad. I know it's a warning but this will not work as expected even if though if would compile. Edited. Thanks for pointing it out! It is actually IHMO, biggest issue with the code, even though only a warning.

Comment: Why it shouldn't work as expected? All this multi-character literals are integers and enum with not fixed underlying type should have underlying type integral type, which can handle ALL enum values. If there is no such type - program is ill-formed.

Comment: @ForEveR I am not telling it will not work for sure for OP. But I get the strong feeling he wants to compare it with some parsed data. What value of will `'=='` have? And how to compare it with a string read from file? I just think this idea will cause troubles. I assume it will not work as OP thinks, because he allows his tokens to be multicharacter and uses type designed for single characters. He would probably need to read token as string compare it to `"=="` and  assign `'=='` to it. I find that cumbersome and I'm quite sure it is not what they expects. Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In declaration

```
TokenType tokenType;
```

in implementation

```
this->TokenType = TType;
```

Look at register of symbols.

Your second line is since `valueInt` of type `int` cannot be converted to `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are 3 errors, first is that data member in class is with lower 't' and you use with upper 'T'. `this->TokenType = TType;` but in class it is defined as `TokenType tokenType;`
The second is `this->valueInt = value;`  value is pointer but valueInt is integer.
maybe you need `this->valueInt = *value;`
The third error in testPrint is again a call to `TokenType` but in class is with lower 't'.

Answer (score 0):

`'=='` is highly suspect. String literals in C++ are written as `"=="`. `'c'` is the numerical value of the single character 'c'. Enums are a name-to-number mapping, not name-to-string. You probably want `namespace TType { const std::string SIGN_DOUBLEEQUALS  = "=="`.

This change means all your other error messages are impacted and may well disappear.

The root cause is that for historical reasons, `'ab'` is allowed but doesn't have a well-defined meaning. Those reasons really don't matter to you; they're just there to keep
ancient code working.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the errors already addressed by the others, here are some ideas for improvement:

```
#ifndef TOKEN_H_
#define TOKEN_H_

class Token {
public:
    enum TokenType {
        INTEGER,
        IDENTIFIER,
        PRINT,
        READ,
        SIGN_PLUS           ='+',
        SIGN_MINUS          ='-',
        SIGN_DIV            ='/',
        SIGN_MUL            ='*',
        SIGN_LESSTHAN       ='<',
        SIGN_GREATERTHAN    ='>',
        SIGN_EQUALS         ='=',
        // SIGN_DOUBLEEQUALS   ='==',
        // SIGN_NOTEQUALS      ='=!=',
        SIGN_NOT            ='!',
    };
private:
    int const line;
    int const column;
    TokenType const tokenType;
    int valueInt; //bei Integern muss Value gespeichert werden
    int const infoKey; //der Key aus der Symtableh
public:
    Token (int const line, int const column, TokenType const tokenType, int const infoKey) :
        line(line), column(column), tokenType(tokenType), infoKey(infoKey) {}
    void setValue (int const value) { valueInt = value; }
    void testPrint () const;
    virtual ~Token ();
};

#endif /* TOKEN_H_ */
```

- The `enum` should be defined within the `Token` class. The way you did it you can not have a variable of type `TokenType` (you could have one of type `TokenType::TType`).
- There is no need for `TokenType.h`. You will never use the `enum` values without `Token.h`.
- Put very simple methods into the hearder, as long as you do not have to `#include` anything for that. Here I did it for the constructor and for `setValue`.
- Use always `const` if possible.

Now here is the `Token.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Token.h"

using namespace std;

void Token::testPrint() const {
    cout << "Token: Line: " << line << " Column: " << column << " TokenType: " << tokenType << " Infokey: " << infoKey << endl;
}

Token::~Token() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

int main () {
        Token (1, 1, Token::SIGN_LESSTHAN, 77) . testPrint ();
}
```

- You have to use `Token::SIGN_LESSTHAN` because the `enum` is now a member.
- the `main` is for illustration only.
- You should not put `using namespace` into any header or before any `#include`.